# How to Retrieve the most recent Identity value and use it in an INSERT statement in SQLServer/Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, identity-column, sql-insert

[EDIT]

In response to Mitch Wheat's advice, inserts now work with `(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'Semi-Fail')`, `(@@IDENTITY, 'Semi-Fail')`; **however**, both produce `NULL` values on select:

```
create clustered index test2_inx ON test2 (test1_id);
```

The following `INSERT`s both produce NULL

```
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('Semi-failure');
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'Semi-failure');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('Semi-failure');
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (@@IDENTITY, 'Semi-failure');
SELECT * FROM test2;
```

The use of `IDENT_CURRENT` does work, however:

```
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('Success');
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (IDENT_CURRENT('test1'), 'Success');
```

... but why can't I get it to work with the other two?

Thank you.

As an aside: coming from Oracle, the notion that a table can be created as anything other than a heap table without being specified as such, is, well, insane. Is that a Cloud thing? Does anyone know the purpose of that?

[/EDIT]

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
 id int identity(1,1)
,value varchar(20)
,CONSTRAINT test1_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE test2 (
 id int
,value varchar(20)
,CONSTRAINT test2_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES test1 (id)
)
```

Insert into test1 statement:

```
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('failure');
```

All of the following fail with the same error:

```
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'fail');
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (select SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'fail');
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES ( (select SCOPE_IDENTITY()) , 'fail');
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (@@IDENTITY, 'fail');
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (select @@IDENTITY, 'fail');
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES ( (select @@IDENTITY), 'fail');
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (IDENT_CURRENT('test1'), 'fail');
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (select IDENT_CURRENT('test1'), 'fail');
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES ( (select IDENT_CURRENT('test1'), 'fail');
```

For each of the above `INSERT` statements, I receive one of the following errors:

```
Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
```

In addition, the following select statements return null, after a `INSERT` into test1:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

Whereas the following returns the correct value:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('test1');
```

Comment: Possibly a stupid question, but you are using the same connection to select SCOPE_IDENTITY(), without letting it close in-between, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

You ***must*** define a clustered index on your tables (as described in the error message you posted).

> Because Microsoft Windows Azure SQL Database does not support heap
>   tables, a table must have a clustered index. If a table is created
>   without a clustered constraint, a clustered index must be created
>   before an insert operation is allowed on the table.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336275.aspx).

Do that, and then `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` should work.

Comment: Thank you @Mitch Wheat. I have made the change but I cannot get the value from SCOPE_IDENTITY. Can you please refer to my edits?

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question rather than munging this one.

Comment: My question is how to insert the most recently generated value from an Identity column in Azure. I thank you for your tip on creating a clustered index, as Azure is different than regular SQLServer, but my the use of `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is retrieving a `NULL value`, and therefore my question still stands.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance with the Clustered Index.